# Firebase facebook login email required

Tags: firebase, facebook-login

I am using facebook login with firebase, but I need the email from the user for the app, and the user can deny the access to the app and in firebase the email will be empty but I will have a lot of problems on the app.

[image]

I want to know if there is a way to ask the email to be required or to ask the user to re-enter another one.